# How can remove Extra space in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, material-design, dart-null-safety

When I used the suffixIcon so space between hint text and underline is little bit show extra and without suffixIcon it's look perfect. if you see in below image I have used the suffixIcon in "New Password" and "Confirm Password" So there is little bit extra space between hint text and underline but in "Old Password" i have not use the suffixIcon So it's look perfect. I have also try with set suffixIcon size but it's not working, So please help me for **how can I remove the extra space when using the suffixIcon?**

You can see below with both code and UI.

[image]

Comment: Don't add code as image, give the code in text format

Answer (score 1):

Use contentPadding property of TextFormField to maintain equal amount of space regardless of if whether it has suffixIcon or not:

```
contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 12),
```